# OEIS A249665 generating function

Tags: power-series, generating-functions, closed-form, oeis

I'm stuck at finding the general term of the sequence
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 14, 28, 56, 118, 254, 541, 1140, 2401, 5074, \ldots$$
According to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A249665), [Colin Barker](http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Colin_Barker) conjectured the recurrence relation to be
$$2\cdot a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+2\cdot a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}+a_{n-5}-a_{n-7}-a_{n-8}$$
and the generating function
$$-\frac{x\cdot (x^3+x-1)}{x^8+x^7-x^5-x^4-2\cdot x^3+x^2-2\cdot x+1}$$
I found the power series of the generating function to be
$$x + x^2 + x^3 + 2 x^4 + 6 x^5 + O(x^5)$$
but I don't know how to proceed.
Moreover I would like to find a closed form formula to get the general $a_n^3$ term, but I believe once I get the general formula for $a_n$ I am done, since $a_n$ has a linear recurrence recurrence implies that also $a_n^3$ has one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Colin Barker's recurrence relation and generating function look consistent with the $a,g,h$ recurrence in OEIS.  I see no reason to expect a simple closed form solution but for large $n$ you may find something like $0.142764774\times 2.113932624^n$ is relatively close