# Transform generating function into linear recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions

This problem is inspired from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604263/oeis-a249665-generating-function). Given a generating function $f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are irreducible polynomials, how to transform it into a linear recurrence relation?